# preg_match_all how to get *all* combinations? Even overlapping ones

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way in the PHP regex functions to get all possible matches of a regex  *even if those matches overlap*?

e.g. Get all the 3 digit substrings '/[\d]{3}/'...

You might expect to get:

"123456" => ['123', '234', '345', '456']

But 
preg_match_all() only returns

['123', '456']

This is because it begins searching again **after** the matched substring (as noted in the documentation):

> "After the first match is found, the subsequent searches are continued on from end of the last match.".

Is there a way around this without writing a custom parser?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look-ahead assertions to the rescue!

```
preg_match_all('/(?=(\d{3}))/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

It basically captures whatever the look-ahead assertion is matching. Since the assertion is zero width, `$matches[0]` will only contain empty strings, but `$matches[1]` will contain the expected captured patterns.

Comment: Ah, I was on the right track. Your answer is certainly an improvement on mine though. Nice work :)

Comment: Thank you. This worked wonderfully. For interest sake in my case I was attempting to match 11 digit Australian Business Numbers (ABNs) that had optional spaces and dashes. My final working regex using your solution (and help from maček) was this:

'/(?=(\b(\d[\s-]*){10}\d\b))/'

The results get passed through a second function to ensure they are a valid ABN using a checksum.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be ideal, but at least it's something.

It looks like you could use a positive lookahead and `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` to get all the string indexes for where a 3-digit number exists

```
$str = "123456";

preg_match_all("/\d(?=\d{2})/", $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

$numbers = array_map(function($m) use($str){
  return substr($str, $m[1], 3);
}, $matches[0]);

print_r($numbers);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 234
    [2] => 345
    [3] => 456
)
```

Comment: That is an ingenious solution. I'll leave the question open a little longer as unfortunately it won't work in my case (other complications I didn't explain in the question) in case someone has another solution. But thank you! I'll give you the point if nothing comes up.

Answer (score 2):

With `\K` inside a lookbehind:

```
preg_match_all('~(?<=\K..).~', '123456', $m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/FqOlR)

Only one character is consumed (the third), the first two are not since they are inside a lookbehind that is a zero-width assertion. But the `\K` gives the start of the match result and the first two are returned (with the third).

Notice: You can't put all the three characters in the lookbehind and write `(?<=\K...)`, because in this case the regex engine will stay forever at the same position in the string.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, really nice one! It works in PHP, funnily when trying it in regex101 the tool throws an [error](https://regex101.com/r/pYPR8g/1): *`\K` This token can not be used in a lookbehind*

Comment: @bobblebubble: yes, the reason is that pcre2 has an extra compilation option: PCRE2_EXTRA_ALLOW_LOOKAROUND_BSK (BSK: BackSlash K). This option is activated in regex101, but not in PHP.

Comment: Amazing how you found that and just read about it myself. Somehow funny how they called this option!

Comment: @bobblebubble: The source: http://pcre.org/pcre2.txt (search: "Extra compile options")